# Filtering an object by property in Ramda.js

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

I'm new to using Ramda.js and am wondering how I can filter an object based on specified properties.

Looking at [`R.filter`](http://ramdajs.com/0.21.0/docs/#filter), it seems that `_.filter` only passes the object *value* and not the property. For instance, the example given in the REPL:

```
var isEven = (n, prop) => {
  console.log(typeof prop);

  // => 
  // undefined
  // undefined
  // undefined
  // undefined

  return n % 2 === 0;
}

R.filter(isEven, {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4}); //=> {b: 2, d: 4}
```

---

If I have the following object:

```
const obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
```

My desired result would be:

```
const filterProp = (x) => /* some filter fn */;

filterProp('b')(obj);

// => {a: 1, c: 3};
```

*How can I use Ramda to filter the properties of an object?*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After digging through the Ramda docs, I found [R.omit](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#omit) which satisfies my particular use case.

```
const obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};

R.omit(['b'], obj);

// => {a: 1, c: 3};
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the [pickBy](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#pickBy) method which allows you to filter a collection based on the keys.

```
const obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
var predicate = (val, key) => key !== 'b';
R.pickBy(predicate, obj);
// => {a: 1, c: 3}
```